# Recognize sound in Action Script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, audio

I want to create a small application that will be able to recognize sound. That is, it will match input sound with sound pattern that user has already recorded. Then, it will output the result (matched or not), Alert.show() for example. 
Can anyone help me ? Thank you in advance...

Comment: It is *not* impossible, but it *is* a non-trivial task -- not one that could reasonably be answered in the SO/QA format.

Comment: Depending on what kind of sounds that you are trying to recognize, [computeSpectrum()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundMixer.html#computeSpectrum()) might be able to reasonably function, given a margin of error. But without more details of what exactly you are trying to do, it is difficult to say.

Comment: The sound kind is very simple, I just want to record "bip" or "clap". They're used as pattern and then, will be compared to the user input sound. Must I implement an algorithm by myself ? I have a little background of sound processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, a french guy named Didier Brun worked on this, and have quite good managed to do a voice recognition engine purely in Flash. Its not exactly a sound recognition engine, but I suppose it could do the trick, with a little more work.
You can find it [here](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=1151).
He demoed it on-stage at the 2010 Amsterdam FITC and it work surprisingly well.

Comment: Thank you, but I've got it several days ago. What I did is sending my sound data to google Speech To Text api and then, get the result :)